# compile multiple WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter via mvn install -Pprofile

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-security

I'm developping a webapp under spring 4 and i wonder if it's possible to activate one or another WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter at compile under maven thanks to profiles.

Example : I have 2 classes

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = false)
@ComponentScan("org.springframework.security.saml")
public class ApplicationContextSecuritySAML extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
...
}
```

And

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = false)
public class ApplicationContextSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
...
}
```

Is there a way to choose one or another at compile thanks to maven ?
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved if anyone interested :

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>profile1</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*</include>
                        </includes>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>com/xxx/xxx/config/ApplicationContextSecuritySAML.java</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>profile2</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*</include>
                        </includes>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>com/xxx/xxx/config/ApplicationContextSecurity.java</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

:)